# Keeping internal HDD as external

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive

I am looking to get a disk to backup all my data in case something hapens and both my internal drives' filesystem get corrupted.

I am thinking of getting an 'internal' hard drive and simply keep it on my desk and plug it in with a SATA hub.My question is: How protected are internal drives left outside(aka on my desk) than the usual '2.5 inch drive in a fancy case with USB' setup?

Are there any risks in leaving a drive outside of a case for long period of time?

Comment: This is a difficult one to have a single answer for - but for the sake of a $15 enclosure, why not protect it?

Comment: Buy an external SATA enclosure and protect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, there is no reason why this wouldn't be ok - if it works internally, it should work externally.

From a practicality point of view - protect the drive!  Static, dust, water, variable heat, impact, the list of potential pitfalls are huge.  Gratned some of these risks (dust, impact) are present both internally and externally - but the risk and impact of such events is greatly magnified when there isn't a huge PC Case surrounding the drive.

Personally, if speed is that critical and time is money, I would recommend you get a USB3 card for your PC and use a drive case - or look into the possibility of a SATA cradle which the drive clips securely into and then ensure that you place the drive cradle somewhere secure and generally out of reach (shelf with cables behind it, behind the PC etc).

Hope thi shelps

Comment: Also, if you are using a mechanical disk (non-SSD) and you are not too fussed about the size then a 3.5" disk is far more robust than it's 2.5" counterpart...

Comment: Very True Big Chris - thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You run risk using 2.5 and/or 3.5 internal drives connected to the dock permanently. External HDD hub is easier to be dropped/touched causing HDD to fall out.

As they often have open electronic parts, except SSD, externally connected they may become dirty, or be shorten and thus damaged.

HDD drives with open electronic circuits (if not SSD) mostly designed to be used inside some cases which serve them as Electro Magnetic protection, so permanent using them in open area can be less reliable, if EM fields are high enough, it can cause a failure.

Take into account other factors, such as humidity, direct sun light, dust, (sound) vibrations and etc.